# Pressing onBackButton is coming back to my fragment but I dont want to

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using navigation components, I have a graph from where I have 3 destinations

```
FragmentA() -> FragmentB() -> FragmentC()
```

When I go from `FragmentA()` to `FragmentB()` , when pressing the backButton I dont want to come again to `FragmentA()`, instead I want to pop to `FragmentC()`, I have set popUpInclusive to true in the action that navigates from `FragmentA()` to `FragmentB()` and set popUpTo `FragmentC()` but when I press backButton on `FragmentB()` it stills going to `FragmentA()`

Whats wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding a listener into the host activity and pop from there the backstack

```
 override fun onBackPressed() {
        when(navController.currentDestination?.id){

            R.id.navigation_success -> {
                navController.popBackStack(R.id.navigation_success,true)
                navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_orders)
            }
            else -> navController.navigateUp()
        }

    }
```

There is a difference between navigateUp and onBackPressed, this two work in different ways, if we use navigateUp we need to touche the navigation graph and from there we can set popupTo and also popupInclusive, but if we are using just the onBackPressed button we need to attach this listener in our main host activity

Answer (score 0):

```
 // This callback will only be called when MyFragment is at least Started.
    val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
        // Handle the back button event
    }
```